# How to solve a linear system of equation with floor function?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ceiling-and-floor-functions, gaussian-elimination

Say I have the linear system of equations of the form:

$\alpha x_1 + \beta x_2 = \lfloor y \rfloor$.

I want to solve for $\alpha$ and $\beta$. For instance, I have

$14 \alpha  = 2$

$ 71 \alpha + 24 \beta = 33 $

$ 134 \alpha + 12 \beta = 36$

(For this problem, $\alpha = 0.2$ and $\beta = 0.8$, but $\alpha + \beta$ need not be $1$, though)

Obviously, without the floor function, this would be a trivial linear system of equations that could be solved through Gauss-Jordan elimination when transformed into a matrix.

I'm wondering if there are similar matrix manipulations to solve this "almost-linear" system of equations. And if, not any other methods that could solve a system of equations like what I have?

Comment: Do you mean $\lfloor 14\alpha \rfloor = 2$ etc. This is different than what you asked.

Comment: If you are solving for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ do not appear inside a floor function, where is the problem? It's still a linear system. The question is not very clear. What is *exactly* the system you have to solve?

Comment: Subbing in $\alpha = 0.2,\beta = 0.8$, your equations should be

\begin{align}14\alpha &= 2.8\\ 71\alpha + 24\beta &= 33.4
\\134\alpha + 12\beta &= 36.4
\end{align} i.e. your $\alpha=0.2$ and $\beta=0.8$ do $\color{red}{not}$ solve the equations you wrote down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean your system to be the following:

$$
\begin{align}
\left \lfloor 14\alpha \right \rfloor \;&= \; 2\\
\left \lfloor 71\alpha + 24\beta \right \rfloor \; &= \; 33 \\
\left \lfloor 134\alpha + 12\beta \right \rfloor \; &= \; 36 \\
\color{white}{text}
\end{align}
$$

This is the equivalent of the following system of inequalities:

$$
\begin{matrix}
2 \quad \le & 14\alpha  & \lt \quad 3\\
33 \quad \le & 71\alpha + 24\beta  & \lt \quad 34 \\
36 \quad \le & 134\alpha + 12\beta  & \lt \quad 37 \\
\color{white}{text} \\
\end{matrix}
$$

This will have an infinite number of solutions, though all the values will be fairly close to the solution you gave (e.g. $\,\alpha = 0.82, \beta = 0.198\,$ and $\,\alpha = 0.79, \beta = 0.204\,$ are also solutions.)

You can solve this graphically as shown below; in this case, $\,\alpha=y\,$ and $\,\beta=x.\,$ Any point in the darker shaded area would be a solution.

[image: System of Double Inequalities]